# Trying to find a Sci-Fi Short Story called "Sarge"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, cyborg

I have a friend who is looking to find a short sci-fi story called "Sarge." The story I am looking for starts off as a letter or message to his adversaries. It is first person from the dog's point of view. He is a hybrid dog or a cyborg dog. He explains in the letter how he was tasked by his recently late owner/ handler to protect a little girl. I am pretty sure the whole story is this message or letter to whom ever is trying to harm the little girl. It was published in a collection of short stories sometime in the 70s or 80s. Can anyone help?

Comment: So you're looking for the collection that the story is in?

Comment: I'm specifically looking for the story, but if I can at least get the title of the collection, I can go out and buy it. I just contacted my friend and I am adding new information above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"[Sergeant Chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergeant_Chip)" - 2004 - Bradley Denton

> The story is told from the point of view of Chip, a specially trained military dog that has been implanted with a microchip that allows him to communicate with his trainer, Captain Dial. The two of them put on many military demonstrations until they are called to active duty in the war. In the war they are caught in an unexpected ambush and eventually come to realize who the "real" enemy is.

[Review](http://www.nyrsf.com/2014/06/sergeant-chip-and-other-novellas-by-bradley-denton-reviewed-by-don-webb.html)

[Wayback Machine retrieval from author website of full text](http://web.archive.org/web/20110809021900/http://bradleydenton.net/sgtchipcomplete.htm)

Comment: This is it!!! Thank you soo soo much!!I was pulling my hair out trying to find it!!

Comment: @MadamLibrarian If this is the one, can you click on the green checkmark to accept it?

Answer (score 5):

There was a [query about a ghostly dog named Sarge](https://www.whatsthatbook.com/?xq=9536) where they received the answer of *[Ghost Stories](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2890695-ghost-stories)* by J.M.R Meagher, published in 1983 Could that be your book?

[image: Book image]

[Google Books confirms it has a story named Sarge](https://books.google.com/books/about/Ghost_stories.html?id=Jw1ub1XBPtgC).

Comment: Yes, not "sci-fi", but in case they're confused. :)

Comment: Thanks for looking guys! It's not about a ghost or d/s romance ;) I appreciate the effort though!!